# segmentation fault while trying to run the program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

This program uses quicksort to sort the numbers followed by the code which places the negative  and positive numbers alternatively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void swap(int *arr,int i,int j)
{
    int temp=arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=temp;
}


int partition(int *arr,int left,int right)
{
    int temp=0;
    int i=left;
    int j=right;

    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(i<=right && arr[i]<=temp)
        i++;
        while(j>=left && arr[j]>=temp)
        j--;
        if(i<j)
        swap(arr,i,j);
    }
 return j;
}

void quick_sort(int *arr,int left,int right)
{
    if(left<right)
    {
        int pivot=partition(arr,left,right);
        quick_sort(arr,left,pivot-1);
        quick_sort(arr,pivot+1,right);
    }
    return ;
}

void nega(int *arr,int left,int right)
{
    int i;

    quick_sort(arr,left,right);

    for(i=0;i<right+1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>=0)
        break;
    }
    int j=i;
    int k;
    for(i=1,k=j;i<j && k<=right;i+=2,k++)
    {
        int temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[k];
        arr[k]=temp;
    }
}


int main()
{
  int i,n;
  int arr[15];

  printf("enter the n:");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  printf("enter the element");
  scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }
    printf("debug");
   nega(arr,0,n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Here the code asks the user to value of n and it takes n elements into the array.
If the value of the n is 1(i.e., for one element)it is working fine.
If the value of the n > 1 (for more than 1 element).It is showing segmentation fault.May be somewhere in the functions it access unaccessible locations.

But,I don't understand why it is not executing `printf("debug");` right after the input to the code.It is directly showing segmentation fault before executing `printf("debug");` and I don't find any cause for segmentation fault before `printf("debug");`.

Can someone point out me what is the problem.Thanks.

Comment: put an 'printf("you entered %d (%i of %i)", arr[i], i, n)' just behind your scanf() inside the for to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question: prints is buffered. So if you program crashes, the buffer is not flushed yet, and "debug" is not printed. Try printing to stderr for logging and error purposes:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Debug");
```

I will try to answer your question about the segfault as well.

Update:

This will result in a negative pivot if all values in arr are above zero:

```
while(j>=left && arr[j]>=temp)
    j--;
```

If you change:

```
int temp = 0;
```

to:
    int temp = arr[left];

It will not give you a segmentation fault and I think it is what you would like to have. Note that this will not fix your sorting algorithm, only specifies where your segfault occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<right+1;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]>=0)
    break;
}
```

This part looks fishy. Can right ever be the last element?